# TypeScript: inferred type from object

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to automatically generate/infer a flexible type from an object literal?

I have the following object:

```
export const config = {
  name: 'foo',
  bar: true,
} as const;
```

I want to automatically generate a flexible type based on this. Something which looks like:

```
type Config = {
  name: string;
  bar: boolean;
}
```

I have tried `type Config = typeof config`, but this gives me a type where `name` must be `'foo'`, etc. All properties are fixed to a single value.

I have also tried the following, but got the same result

```
export type Config = {
  [K in keyof typeof config]: typeof config[K];
};
```

I could of course write a separate type def, but my actual use case is more complex than the above example.

Comment: Just remove `as const`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out my second example works as long as `as const` is removed from the object literal used as the template. The readonly attribute can be added to the interred type:

```
export const config = {
  name: 'foo',
  bar: true,
}; // No `as const`

export type Readonly<Config = {
  [K in keyof typeof config]: typeof config[K];
}>; // Make this type read-only
```